# compare two IntList / processing

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, passwords, processing

I want to make a lock screen with a security password.
I am storing a password in IntList **password**, and attempts are appending to the IntList **attempt** when the user is clicking the button, with the button ID (this part is working alright):

```
IntList password = new IntList(14, 2, 12);
IntList attempt = new IntList();

draw() {
    if (bClick==true) {
      attempt.append(pressed_btn);         
    }
}
```

Now the question is how do I compare two IntArrays and perform some action (switch to the isLoggedIn condition) once they are the same? I am trying that but it does not work:

```
if (attempt.equals(password)) {
  println("attempt equals password");
  isLoggedIn=true;
}
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What is IntList? if this is your own class you can implement your own equality logic in it. What programming language is this? you tagged it as java but it looks strange for java code.

Comment: https://processing.org/reference/IntList.html  I am doing it in Processing, but this class is taken from Java

Answer (score 0):

To compare lists you have to iterate over them and compare the individual entries. The code below shows how it works, though I suggest implementing 'isLoggedIn' a different way than I used below.

```
IntList password = new IntList(14, 2, 12);
IntList attempt = new IntList();
boolean isLoggedIn = true;

attempt.append(14);    
attempt.append(2);    
attempt.append(12);    

for (int i = 0; i < attempt.size(); i++)
{
  if (password.get(i) != attempt.get(i))
  {
    isLoggedIn=false;
  }
}

if (isLoggedIn)
{
  println("You are logged in");
} else
{
  println("Password incorrect");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have actually just sorted it. This worked:

```
if  (password.toString().equals(attempt.toString())) { 
  isLoggedIn=true;
}
```